# Automapper medium trust problem. Unable to solve it

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, automapper

I deployed my site and getting error due to automapper medium trust.

Any solution?

```
[SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet) +0
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(CodeAccessPermission cap, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +31
   System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand() +46
   System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod.PerformSecurityCheck(Type owner, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean skipVisibility) +9461551
   System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod..ctor(String name, Type returnType, Type[] parameterTypes, Type owner, Boolean skipVisibility) +40
   AutoMapper.DelegateFactory.CreateDynamicMethod(MemberInfo member, Type sourceType) +585
   AutoMapper.DelegateFactory.CreateSet(PropertyInfo property) +128
   AutoMapper.Internal.PropertyAccessor..ctor(PropertyInfo propertyInfo) +122
   AutoMapper.ReflectionHelper.ToMemberAccessor(MemberInfo accessorCandidate) +294
   AutoMapper.TypeMapFactory.CreateTypeMap(Type sourceType, Type destinationType, IMappingOptions options) +521
   AutoMapper.Configuration.CreateTypeMap(Type source, Type destination, String profileName) +156
   AutoMapper.Configuration.CreateMap(String profileName) +179
   AutoMapper.Configuration.CreateMap() +92
   AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap() +98
```

Answer (score 0):

An educated guess here ...but are you running in a hosted environment where your app runs in medium and not full trust? If so you will need to try to grant your assembly full trust because of the reflection emit code.

Comment: Did you ever fix this issue?